# Listbox Bug with SelectedIndex and Value?

Tags: c#, asp.net, listbox

I think I found a bug in the use of the Listbox.
Example: ListBox with Editbutton which loads it into special fields:

The listbox has 4 Items:

1. PhoneNumber: +15454545 (Value 2)(Index 0)
2. Email: Test@testmail.com (Value 1)(Index 1)
3. FaxNumber: +1515515151 (Value 3)(Index 2)
4. Email: Test2@testmail.com (Value 1)(Index 3)

Then the editbuttoncode:

```
protected void EditKOFC(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (ListBoxKOFC.SelectedItem == null)
            {
                LabelMPE.Text = "Please select first!";
                ModalPopupExtender1.Show();
            }
            else
            {

                string value = ListBoxKOFC.SelectedValue;
                Session["EditID"] = ListBoxKOFC.SelectedIndex;
                string[] meineStrings = ListBoxKOFC.SelectedItem.Text.Split(new Char[] { ':' });
                string text = meineStrings[1];
                string text2 = text.Substring(1);
                TextBoxKOFC.Text = text2;

                foreach (ListItem item in DropDownListKOFC.Items)
                {
                    item.Selected = false;
                    if (item.Value == value)
                    {
                        item.Selected = true;
                    }
                }
                editing = true;
                AddKOFC.Text = "Save";
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            GlobalFunctions.Error_Log(ex, ex.TargetSite.ToString());
        }
    }
```

And there I get the Problem.
When I select the first three items, its all fine. When I select the 4th item, it uses all the data from the second one, even if they have different Indexes!

Does Value affect the Index here, and if yes, why ?!
Its really a problem for me, because i need to store the contacttype in the Value. (1= Email, 2 = Phone etc);

Thanks allready!

Edit:
To clarify: The Edit-Button is a Button itself outside the ListBox.

```
<asp:TableRow>
            <asp:TableCell>
                <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" ID="UpdatePanel2">
                    <Triggers>
                        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="AddKOFC" EventName="Click" />
                    </Triggers>
                    <ContentTemplate>
                        <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="DropDownListKOFC" />
                    </ContentTemplate>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>
            </asp:TableCell>
            <asp:TableCell>
                <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" ID="UpdatePanel1">
                    <Triggers>
                        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="AddKOFC" EventName="Click" />
                    </Triggers>
                    <ContentTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="TextBoxKOFC" />
                    </ContentTemplate>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>
            </asp:TableCell><asp:TableCell>
                <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" ID="UP2">
                    <ContentTemplate>
                        <asp:Button runat="server" ID="AddKOFC" OnClick="AddContactInformation" Text="Add Contactinformation" />
                        <asp:HiddenField ID="HFAdd" runat="server" />
                        <ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender1" runat="server" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground"
                            TargetControlID="HFAdd" PopupControlID="PanelChoose" BehaviorID="MPEchoose">
                        </ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender>
                        <asp:Panel ID="PanelChoose" runat="server" BorderStyle="Solid" BackColor="ButtonShadow">
                            <asp:Label ID="LabelMPE" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                            <asp:Table ID="Table3" runat="server">
                                <asp:TableRow>
                                    <asp:TableCell>
                                        <asp:Button ID="ButtonOK" runat="server" Text="Ok" />
                                    </asp:TableCell>
                                </asp:TableRow>
                            </asp:Table>
                        </asp:Panel>
                    </ContentTemplate>
                    <Triggers>
                        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="AddKOFC" EventName="Click" />
                        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ButtonOK" EventName="Click" />
                    </Triggers>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>
            </asp:TableCell></asp:TableRow>
        <asp:TableRow>
            <asp:TableCell>
                <asp:Label ID="Label13" runat="server"></asp:Label>
            </asp:TableCell></asp:TableRow>
        <asp:TableRow>
            <asp:TableCell>
                <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" ID="UP3">
                    <Triggers>
                        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="AddKOFC" EventName="Click" />
                    </Triggers>
                    <ContentTemplate>
                        <asp:ListBox runat="server" ID="ListBoxKOFC" ToolTip="The way to contact this person">
                        </asp:ListBox>
                    </ContentTemplate>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>
            </asp:TableCell><asp:TableCell>
                <asp:Button ID="ButtonUpdate" runat="server" Text="Edit" OnClick="EditKOFC" />
            </asp:TableCell><asp:TableCell>
                <asp:Button ID="ButtonDelete" runat="server" Text="Delete" OnClick="DeleteKOFC" />
            </asp:TableCell></asp:TableRow>
        <asp:TableRow>
```

Edit2 for more clarification(or whatever):

[image]

This is how it looks.
Then i want to edit the 4th item:

[image]

And when I debug:

[image]

The 4th Item is not selected ... even if you see in the picture befor, it is!!

If I look at the ListBoxKOFC itself:

[image]

And when the code is done, the wrong item got selected and loaded to edit:

[image]

But as you can see in the 4. Screenshot -> The index of the item i want to edit is three.
Only the value is the same.
But WHY cant the value be the same, the index is another allways ...

Does the Value work as Index here ?! (Cant be, but atm im not sure anymore ...) Or is the Value just bugged ?

Comment: `ListBox with Editbutton`??

Comment: Ups, the EditButton is a Button itself outside of the ListItem. I will update the Question.

Comment: @DatRid: Ok, but am i the only one who does not understand the problem? What are you trying to achieve? `ListBox.SelectedValue` returns the value of the **first** selected item. So if all are selected it returns always the value of the first item. A `DropDownList` on the other hand has only single-selection. So if it contains the same items also the first item will be selected. I also don't understand the meaning of the indices and values in the LiustBox-Items.

Comment: @Tim Schmelter: Well I allways select only 1 Item, not more!

Comment: @TimSchmelter: Well the i just wrote down how the Listbox is filled.

Comment: @All: -> http://vaderpi.com/blog/?p=208 This is nearly the same case, except that i have allways only one selected. I dont have any multiselection.

Comment: Well guys, i updated the question again.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Maybe there is a easy way to accomplish. I look at the code and I don't really understand the purpouse of it.

Comment: Well, i need to store the index of the item i changed, because I need to save the right item. I allready did a workarround, but i just wanted to know why it works like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep. Your problem is having two items with the same Value. The ASP.Net dropdown renders to the browser as a standard HTML select control, with the form:

```
<select name="cars">
<option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
<option value="saab">Saab</option>
<option value="fiat">Fiat</option>
<option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_select2

Each option is supposed to have a unique value.

Remember that when the postback happens, the ASP.Net engine creates a new instance of your page and applies the view state that came in with the request. When it tries to re-create your dropdown control, it searches for an option with the correct value and stops when it finds one.

Comment: Ah ... This is sad. Well atleast i was able to find a easy workarround ... Thanks!

Comment: I remember feeling the same way when I tried to do something similar a few years ago.

Answer (score 1):

I think I once had this problem before. It turned out that you cannot set ListBox sort property to true; otherwise the index will be useless.

But this might not be your case.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I didnt set the sortprotperty at all. I will check if its default true or false ;)

Comment: Okay, there is no sortproperty at all at my Listbox but thanks!

Comment: Oops. I thought you mean Windows Forms ListBox control.

Comment: I don't understand your question, either. There is a ListBoxKOFC, bu what is DropDownListKOFC? Where is the problem in your code?

Comment: Nope, as you see in the tags, its asp.net :) I will clarify it more :D

Comment: That's weird. Note that ListItem has Value and Text. Did you accidentally set same value to item #2 and #4??

Comment: As explained, its not accidentally the same value, its wanted ... The value can be same, but the index should be another shouldnt it ? Or WHY cant the Value not be the same ?! I mean its just the value, not a index which must be unique ?!

Comment: value is important because in fact you are using it in the loop to make the selection again. So if there are several elements with the same value, per your code, only the last element will prevail.

Comment: @DatRid Due to the nature of HTTP request (which is off topic), you *SHOULD* assign unique values for each ListItem in ListBox. It's critical.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should not have 2 item with same value in a list box. If you must have duplicate value then you can't use value as condition.

Asp .Net does not treat the Value work as Index. It is your code that use value as condition which is wrong(refer below).

```
if (item.Value == value)
{
    item.Selected = true;
}
```

**Solution:**
You need to use index as your condition. Try below code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < DropDownListKOFC.Items.Count; i++)
{
    DropDownListKOFC.Items[i].Selected = false;

    if (i == ListBoxKOFC.SelectedIndex)
    {
      DropDownListKOFC.Items[i].Selected = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Well - this would be a problem later ... But current it allready has the wrong Item selected at `string value = ListBoxKOFC.SelectedValue;
                Session["EditID"] = ListBoxKOFC.SelectedIndex;` It is like Bill said i think ;) But thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the others for helping me to understand the problem!
I will just share my little workarround, maybe it will help someone!

Add a random value to the current value while you load it:

```
Random rnd = new Random();
int random = rnd.Next(1,1000000);
```

Then add it togheter with the value:

```
ListItem listitem = new ListItem(text, value + random.ToString(), true);
ListBox.Items.Add(listitem);
```

And if you need it, just use substring:

```
string value = ListBox.SelectedValue;
value = value.Substring(0, 1);
```

But this will only work if you have allways the same number of numbers infront of the random.